# Is dart:intl broken? / DateFormat to complicated

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I using Dart Editor 0.3.7_r18717 (means the editor is up to date (Feb 2013)

```
import 'dart:intl';
```

Shows an error "Cannot find referenced source"

If I import the package via pub

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

then compiling to JS dart2js fails with some weird errors...

What I want is simply something like this:

```
final String time = new DateFormat("HH:mm:ss","de").format(new DateTime.now());
```

It's not clear at all why the locale is needed in such case...

thx

[**Update**]
OK - I know "weird errors" means nothing - so here is the output if I import the following two packages:

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

String getTime() {
    final String time = new DateFormat("HH:mm:ss","en_US").format(new DateTime.now());
    //final String time = "20:05:00";
return time;
}
```

*Output*:

```
Running dart2js...
Using snapshot /Developer/dart/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/compiler/implementation/dart2js.dart.snapshot
Wrote /Users/mikemitterer/dart/WebSockets.SAMPLE/web/out/jrelaisui.html_bootstrap.dart.js [410.0kb written in 5.3 seconds]
build.dart --machine --changed=web/jrelaisui.dart
file:/Users/mikemitterer/dart/WebSockets.SAMPLE/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

Uncaught Error: NoSuchMethodError : method not found: '_addFromInteger@0x36924d72'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [80]
Stack Trace:
    #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch:1737:25)
    #1      int.+ (dart:core-patch:1324:33)
    #2      Parser.translateCharacter    (package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/parser.dart:4380:167)
    #3      Parser.computeStringValue (package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/parser.dart:376:33)
    #4      Parser.parseStringLiteral (package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/parser.dart:3451:76)
    #5      Parser.parsePrimaryExpression (package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/parser.dart:3163:32)
    #6      Parser.parseAssignableExpression (package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/parser.dart:837:51)
    #7      Parser.parsePostfixExpression (package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/parser.dart:3061:51)
```

...

*Output - Clean Up Source:*

```
build.dart --machine --clean
file:/Users/mikemitterer/dart/HelloWebComponent/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

'package:html5lib/src/encoding_parser.dart': Error: line 65 pos 14: class 'EncodingBytes' overrides function 'skip' of super class 'Iterable' with incompatible parameters
  String skip([CharPreciate skipChars]) {
             ^

build.dart --machine --clean
file:/Users/mikemitterer/dart/todomvc/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

'package:html5lib/src/encoding_parser.dart': Error: line 65 pos 14: class 'EncodingBytes' overrides function 'skip' of super class 'Iterable' with incompatible parameters
  String skip([CharPreciate skipChars]) {
```

...

Thats what I mean with "weird" :-)

Comment: The last error seems to hint that some of the packages may not be up-to-date perhaps? Or do not align with the SDK version you are running...

Answer (score 2):

The package syntax is the correct one, this should work:

```dart
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  print(new DateFormat.yMd().format(new DateTime.now()));
}
```

What "weird errors" are you talking about?

Comment: I'm also getting these errors. It seems that it's because the `intl` library is not up to date with the latest SDK version. :/

Answer (score 0):

import "dart:intl"; won't work to import it because it's not one of the "core" dart libraries, it has to be imported as a package. The errors you're listing in dart2js don't look like they're coming from internationalization code, but from web_ui and from the analyzer_experimental package. What happens if you comment out the lines that use internationalization and compile using dart2js?